# Study A Class Amplifier Schematic

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

Thank you all, let me ask about schematic design A Class Amplifier schematic on internet, explain to me about how much voltage amplifier the design? 10x times or 100x times, and how we calculate the 10-14 watt power? [image]

please explain step by step, thank you very much

Comment: *explain to me about how much voltage amplifier the design* Explain **what**? Are you asking to explain **how** to do design? Depending on your current skill level that takes years to master!

Comment: are you any recomendation step how to study, i only understand basic amplifier, for advanced i stii confuse

Answer (score 0):

base voltage is about 3 volts

emitter voltage about 2 volts

emitter current = 2v/150 or 12mA

The reac thus is 2 ohms (transconductance is 0.48 amps/volt)

the gain of the transistor is 1.8K / 2 ohms or about 900x

this circuit also has huge input capacity caused by Miller multiplication of Cob * gain of the 2n3904; this will be about 10,000 picofarads

but this circuit also has global negative feedback, implemented right at the input

Comment: thank your for your answer, are you any recomendation website to understand that schematic?